Creating a trail of instances behind an object that moves along a curve in geometry nodes
I've been trying to create an effect that replicates droplets of water falling down a surface. I have droplets of water (as ico spheres) that move along curves that are on the surface of the object. Now the question is, how do I periodically create droplets after the object has passed this position. I would like to control the size of the intervals between trailing droplets(random value from min to max), the size of the trailing droplets(random value from min to max) and the speed at wich the leading droplet falls(sometimes with a delay or as a loop so that all of them do not start and end at the same time).
The approach I used is below:
The sample_curve node is used to move the leading droplets along the curves.
Here we can see that the trailing droplets are not at the same level as the leading one.

I have tried to use the greater_than node to create droplets whose height is greater that the leading droplet, but it failed. this method also would not allow for as much control as I wanted(written in bold). Can someone help me? This is my first post, if I have been imprecise I would love feedback to give more precise information.
